# Spring MVC File Upload - Only in IE - Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 10053

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

Using Spring MVC File upload - it works fine with all browsers except IE. When try to upload file throws error saying RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available’. Using WebSphere Portal v8 and Spring MVC Portlet v4.1.3. 
Stuck with this for past two days, couldn't figure out the source of issue, any help is appreciated!

### Controller:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=upload")
public void onUpload(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse, Model model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("messageForm") MessageForm messageForm, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

if (result.hasErrors()) {
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action","send");
} else {                    
    CommonsMultipartFile multipartFile =  messageForm.getMessageList().get(0).getFile();
    long size = multipartFile.getSize();

    if(message != null && message.getAttachmentList() != null && message.getAttachmentList().size() > 3) {
        result.rejectValue("messageList[0].attachmentList", "org.schoolsfirstfcu.messagecenter.validator.file.count");
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action","send");         
    } else if (size > 5242881 ) {//TODO Make the file size configurable. 
        result.rejectValue("messageList[0].file", "org.schoolsfirstfcu.sendmessage.validator.fileupload.invalidSize");
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action","send");         
    }                                
        ArrayList<Message> messageList = messageForm.getMessageList();                      
        String orgName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();               
        String filePath = "C:\\upload\\" + messageForm.getMessageList().get(0).getId() + orgName;
        File dest = new File(filePath);
        try {
            multipartFile.transferTo(dest);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }               
}
..
..
model.addAttribute("messageForm", messageForm); 
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action","send");
}

@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(RenderRequest actionRequest,RenderResponse actionResponse, Object handler, Exception exception) {        
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
    if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException)
        model.put("fileSizeError", "true");
    else        
        model.put("otherError", "true");            

    if (messageForm != null) {       
        Message message = messageForm.getMessageList().get(0);         
        if(message.getMessageCatList() == null || !(message.getMessageCatList().size() > 0)) {
            ......
        }   
    }        
    model.put("messageForm", messageForm);        
    return new ModelAndView("send", model);
}
```

### View:

```
function submitFormUpload(){        
    var two ='<portlet:actionURL><portlet:param name="action"      value="upload"/></portlet:actionURL>';        
    document.forms["replyForm"].action = two;        
    document.forms["replyForm"].submit();
    document.getElementById("replyForm").submit();
}

<portlet:actionURL var="sendURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="send"></portlet:param>
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form method="post" id="replyForm" commandName="messageForm" action="${sendURL}" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
        <portlet:defineObjects />
        <br />

    <c:forEach items="${messageForm.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="status">
    <TABLE>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD align="left">Add up to 4 files,
                maximum size is 5MB each.</TD>
            <span name="msgInvalidFile" id="msgInvalidFile" class="errorMessage" nowrap=""><form:errors path="messageList[${status.index}].file" /></span>
            <span name="msgBodyValError" id="msgBodyValError" class="errorMessage" nowrap=""><form:errors path="messageList[${status.index}].attachmentList" /></span>
            <c:if test="${fileSizeError}">                                                                                                          
                    <span name="msgBodyValError" id="msgBodyValError" class="errorMessage" nowrap=""><spring:message code="org.schoolsfirstfcu.sendmessage.validator.fileupload.invalidSize"/></span>
            </c:if> 
            <c:if test="${otherError}">                                                                                                         
                    <span name="msgBodyValError" id="msgBodyValError" class="errorMessage" nowrap=""><spring:message code="org.schoolsfirstfcu.sendmessage.validator.fileupload.generalError"/></span>
            </c:if>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD align="left" id="fileUploadWrapper">
                <form:input path="messageList[${status.index}].file" type="file"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                <form:hidden path="messageList[${status.index}].file"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                <input name="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn" type="submit" value="Attach" onclick="disabledConfirm_exit=true; javascript:submitFormUpload();" />                                                                                                      
            </TD>
        </TR>                                                                                               
    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>    
    </c:forEach>            
</form:form>
```

### reply-portlet.xml:

```
<!-- File Upload -->
<bean id="portletMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.multipart.CommonsPortletMultipartResolver">  
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="41943048"/>
<property name="maxInMemorySize" value="41943048" />
</bean>
```

### Error:

3/2/15 17:22:16:690 PST] 000000c3 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/2/15 17:22:16:690 PST] 0000030f DispatcherPor W org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet processHandlerException Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view
                                 org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart portlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.springframework.web.portlet.multipart.CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.multipart.CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherPortlet.java:994)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doActionService(DispatcherPortlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:533)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processAction(FrameworkPortlet.java:473)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:77)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.el.init.AttributeCopyFilter.doFilter(AttributeCopyFilter.java:108)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetPortletFilter.java:73)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.PropertyBrokerActionFilter.doFilter(PropertyBrokerActionFilter.java:749)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:176)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.dpr.portlet.impl.ProcessActionMemoFilter.doFilter(ProcessActionMemoFilter.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.plm.GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.java:218)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.filter.impl.GlobalPortletFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletFilter.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.wps.pcm.scoping.filter.PCMScopingFilter.doFilter(PCMScopingFilter.java:103)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:69)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:527)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doAction(PortletServletCollaborator.java:59)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doAction(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:117)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doAction(CacheCollaborator.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:101)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doAction(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:158)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:549)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:76)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doAction(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:50)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doAction(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.action(PortletInvokerImpl.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doAction(ExtCollaborator.java:60)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doAction(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:76)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.doAction(IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.java:94)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.processPortletAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:154)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$1.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:59)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeProcessAction(PortletInvokerImpl.java:55)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$3.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:121)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:182)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeProcessAction(PortletInvokerImpl.java:119)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.event.ActionEvent.execute(ActionEvent.java:78)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.event.EventQueueManager.processEventLoop(EventQueueManager.java:114)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.performEvents(PortletContainerImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.performEvents(PortletContainerImpl.java:287)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPActionPhase.processPortlets(WPActionPhase.java:3975)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPActionPhase.execute(WPActionPhase.java:1172)
at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractActionPhase.next(AbstractActionPhase.java:146)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:305)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:686)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:411)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:780)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:96)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1388)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:110)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:197)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.SupportedLocalesFilter.doFilter(SupportedLocalesFilter.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilterWithoutProjectID(ProjectIdFilter.java:405)
at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilter(ProjectIdFilter.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:103)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3815)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
```

Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.portlet.PortletFileUpload.parseRequest(PortletFileUpload.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.multipart.CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.java:154)
... 159 more
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.read(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:217)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:184)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.fillABuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:4175)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readSingleBlock(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3407)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readBodyBuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3513)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.getRequestBodyBuffer(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:1791)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.bufferIsGood(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:371)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.read(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:265)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.read(HttpInputStream.java:322)
at com.ibm.wps.state.streams.LeafInputStream.read(LeafInputStream.java:93)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ResettableRequestStream.read(ResettableRequestStream.java:185)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:617)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:634)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1023)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:1003)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
... 161 more
```

[3/2/15 17:29:09:032 PST] 000000c2 filter        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter Compression Filter: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:590)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flushBytes(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:433)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:383)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.streams.DeferredLeafOutputStream.write(DeferredLeafOutputStream.java:227)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.streams.DeferredResettableOutputStream.write(DeferredResettableOutputStream.java:232)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.streams.misc.ResettableBufferedOutputStream$Proxy.copy(ResettableBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
    at com.ibm.utilities.streams.buffering.BufferedOutputStreamProxy.internalCopy(BufferedOutputStreamProxy.java:204)
    at com.ibm.utilities.streams.buffering.BufferedOutputStreamProxy.internalFlush(BufferedOutputStreamProxy.java:225)
    at com.ibm.utilities.streams.buffering.BufferedOutputStreamProxy.close(BufferedOutputStreamProxy.java:110)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.streams.misc.ResettableBufferedOutputStream$Proxy.close(ResettableBufferedOutputStream.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.streams.misc.BufferedOutputStreamAdapter.close(BufferedOutputStreamAdapter.java:86)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.streams.misc.ResettableBufferedOutputStream.close(ResettableBufferedOutputStream.java:241)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ResettableResponseStream.close(ResettableResponseStream.java:192)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 10053  An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

```
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:478)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:396)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.writeAIO(AioSocketIOChannel.java:282)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.processAsyncWriteRequest(AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:54)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.writeInternal(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:382)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.write(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:353)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.asynchWrite(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2446)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.sendOutgoing(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2233)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.sendResponseBody(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:883)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferAsynch(WCChannelLink.java:517)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferResponse(WCChannelLink.java:494)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBuffer(WCChannelLink
```

Comment: The issue popping up again now, even after rewriting the entire to asynchronous file upload using AJAX. this occurs only during form submit, i.e. submitting form that has certain file types such as .JPG and .PNG in it. meaning when I upload the same types using jquery form plugin and AJAX update the page, these types gets submitted in ajax, any idea?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the maxConnections?
http://wassupport.blogspot.com/2013/04/technote-javaioioexception-async-io.html

Answer (score -2):

I faced same issue javascript was submitting twice.

Resolving this solved issue

Comment: Doesn't look like an answer.